# Changing MySQL TINYINT(1) with an html checkbox and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to change the bool preset in MySQL using an html form which calls to a PHP page to input the information into the table.

Here's the code:

addEvent.php

```
$all_day = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['all_day']);

if ($all_day != '1')
{
$all_day = '0';
}


$sql="INSERT INTO db . table (title, start, end, all_day)
VALUES ('$title', '$start', '$end', '$all_day')";
```

html form:

```
All Day?: <input type="checkbox" name="all_day" inputValue="1">
```

The issue I am having is that no matter what I try and do the value of "$all_day" isn't changing from 0 to 1. If anyone could point out the issue it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for strings. `all_day` is not a string. You should convert it to  0 or 1 with `$all_day = (int)(bool)$_POST['all_day']` instead. It will be automatically set to 0 if empty or 0 and 1 if anything else.

Howover, note that if the checkbox is not checked, `$_POST['all_day']` is not set at all and reading it will throw a `Notice` (that might be suppressed depending on your PHP settings). So you might want to do this instead:

```
$all_day = (int)isset($_POST['all_day']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong attribute. Use `value=""` instead of `inputValue`.

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $all_day = isset($_POST['all_day']) ? $_POST['all_day'] : 0;
    // defaults to 0 if not checked

    $prepare = 'INSERT INTO `table_name` (title, start, end, all_day) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    $stmt = $con->prepare($prepare);
    // assuming $title, $start, $end is declared on your end
    $stmt->bind_param('sssi', $title, $start, $end, $all_day);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
        // inserted
    } else {
        // it did not insert
    }
}


?>

<form method="POST">
    <!-- inputValue? no! the correct attribute is "value" -->
    All Day?: <input type="checkbox" name="all_day" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Just to clear things:

- That checkbox value will not change to zero if the checkbox is unchecked, what happens is upon form submission, if that checkbox is unchecked, it will be undefined in `$_POST`.
- So if it is checked, just get the value, if not, just default to `0.`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing inputValue to value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all_day" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats nothing to do with php. It can be done by using `value=""` attribute. It specifies the value of an  element. Use the code given below

```
All Day?: <input type="checkbox" name="all_day" value="1">
```

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning during your if clause

```
 If ($var! = '1')
```

You are doing two things wrong.

1) assigning var to 1 where you should be using !==

And 2) trying to validate var as a string instead of an integer (lose the quotes)

Comment: This isn't even valid syntax, and where did you see it in his code at all?